# in Spring mvc,how to exclude java entity from object mapper xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in my spring mvc application, we are using the below object mapper configuration.

```
<property name="objectMapper">
 <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
 <property name="propertyNamingStrategy">
 <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy$PascalCaseStrategy" /></property>
</bean></property>
```

This configuration is applying for all java entity classes. i want to exclude one java entity(ie,when we pass one dto, it should not be changed by this object mapper configuration).Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried adding extra @JsonProperty to this particular DTO? This annotation, placed directly on your DTO's field should override global settings.

Comment: Actually we are using third party entity files. we are not able to implement @jsonproperty in entity classes.Instead, do we have any option to exclude these entities in xml?.

Comment: Well, you could implement your own JsonSerializer and register it in ObjectMapper.